# How do I grab hold of a pop-up that is opened from a frame?

Tags: testing, web, watin

I am testing a website using WatiN.
On one of the pages I get a "report" in an Iframe, within this I frame there is a link to download and save the report.  But since the only way to get to the link is to use frame.Link(...) the pop-up closes immediately after opening; Code snippet below

//Click the create graph button

ie.Button(Find.ById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_btnCreateGraph")).Click();

```
  //Lets export the data

  ie.Div(Find.ById("colorbox"));

  ie.Div(Find.ById("cboxContent"));

  ie.Div(Find.ById("cboxLoadedContent"));

  Thread.Sleep(1000);//Used to cover performance issues

  Frame frame = ie.Frame(Find.ByName(frameNameRegex));

  for (int Count = 0; Count < 10000000; Count++) {double nothing = (Count/12); }//Do nothing I just need a short pause


  //SelectList waits for a postback which does not occur.
  try
  {

        frame.SelectList(Find.ById("rvReport_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00")).SelectByValue("Excel");

  }

  catch (Exception)

  {

       //Do nothing

  }

  //Now click export

  frame.Link(Find.ById("rvReport_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01")).ClickNoWait();

  IE ieNewBrowserWindow = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(urlRegex));

  fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(150); 

  fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(200);
```

I have tried using ie instead of frame which is why all those ie.Div's are present.
if I use frame the pop-up window opens and closes instantly.
If I use ie I get a link not found error.
If I click on the link manually, while the test is "trying to find the link" the file will download correctly.
I have changed the code to use a different page that doe not have the frame and I still get the same problem download pop-up closes instantly.

[STAThread]

```
  public void TestForMeterDataExport()

  {

      // Open a new Internet Explorer window and

      // goto the website.

      IE ie = new IE("https://<URL>", true);

      FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler("C:\\Documents and Settings\\karnold\\Desktop\\MeterUsageReport_Large.xls");

      Regex urlRegex = new Regex("<URL>\\?Mode=true&ReportID=[a-z A-Z 0-9]{30,33}&ControlID=[a-z A-Z 0-9]{30,33}&Culture=1033&UICulture=1033&ReportStack=1&OpType=Export&FileName=BuildingMeterDataReport&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=Excel");


      //Find the Username text field and input the user ID

      ie.TextField(Find.ByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUsername")).TypeText("<Name>");


      //Find the Password text field and input the password

      ie.TextField(Find.ByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPassword")).TypeText("PASS");


      //Go ahead and login 

      ie.Button(Find.ByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$butLogin")).Click();

      //Let's use the Reports Tab

      ie.Link(Find.ByUrl("https://<URL>")).Click(); 

      // Let's get the meter data

      ie.Link(Find.ByUrl("https://<URL>")).Click();

      //Let's choose University of 

      ie.SelectList(Find.ById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_ucFacility_ddlFacility")).SelectByValue("5041");

      //Set the date range for which we want to get data
      ie.TextField(Find.ById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_DateRangePicker1_dpBeginDate_TextBox")).TypeText("12/09/10");

      ie.TextField(Find.ById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_DateRangePicker1_dpEndDate_TextBox")).TypeText("12/10/10"); 

      //Click the create report button
      ie.Button(Find.ById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_TopBoxContentPlaceHolder_btnSubmit")).ClickNoWait();

      //Lets export the data

      Thread.Sleep(2000);

      //SelectList waits for a postback which does not occur.

      try

      {

          ie.SelectList(Find.ById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentAreaContentPlaceHolder_ContentAreaContentPlaceHolder_rvMain_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00")).SelectByValue("Excel");

      }

      catch (Exception)

      {


          ie.SelectList(Find.ById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentAreaContentPlaceHolder_ContentAreaContentPlaceHolder_rvMain_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00")).FireEventNoWait("onchange");

          //fire the postback event

      }

      //Now click export
      ie.Link(Find.ById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentAreaContentPlaceHolder_ContentAreaContentPlaceHolder_rvMain_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01")).ClickNoWait();

      IE ieNewBrowserWindow = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(urlRegex));

      fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(10);
      fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(20);

  }// close TestForMeterDataExport()
```

Hopefully some one can tell me what I am doing wrong.  Thank you

Here is the error that I get when the program can't find the handle maybe it will help
TestCase 'M:WebTest.CommandLine.WatiNConsoleWebAndDB.TestForMeterDataExport'
failed: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
    at SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2.get_Document()
    at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEBrowser.get_NativeDocument()
    at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEWaitForComplete.WaitForCompleteOrTimeout()
    at WatiN.Core.WaitForCompleteBase.DoWait()
    at WatiN.Core.DomContainer.WaitForComplete(IWait waitForComplete)
    at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.AttachToIeHelper.FinishInitializationAndWaitForComplete(IE ie, SimpleTimer timer, Boolean waitForComplete)
    at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.AttachToIeHelper.Find(Constraint findBy, Int32 timeout, Boolean waitForComplete)
    at WatiN.Core.Browser.AttachTo(Type browserType, Constraint constraint, Int32 timeout)
    at WatiN.Core.Browser.AttachTo(Type browserType, Constraint constraint)
    at WatiN.Core.Browser.AttachTo[T](Constraint constraint)
    Web+DB_test_app.cs(139,0): at WebTest.CommandLine.WatiNConsoleWebAndDB.TestForMeterDataExport()

Comment: could you format your code correctly please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Baptiste for the pointer.

//Set the handles and the file save as name

```
      FileDownloadHandler handler = new FileDownloadHandler("MeterUsageReport_Large_Iframe.xls");

      // add a watcher to look for the save file local

      ie.AddDialogHandler(handler);

      //Do not close dialog boxes immediately

      ie.DialogWatcher.CloseUnhandledDialogs = false;

      //create a single use instance that will be easily cleaned up and avoid having windows open after we are done with them

      using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, handler))

      {
          //Now click export

          frame.Link(Find.ById("rvReport_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01")).ClickNoWait();

          //Grab hold of the poup dialog and download the file             
          handler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(30);
          handler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(35);
      }
```

Now for the fun this will only work if all of the work is done on localhost.
if you need to hit a server that is not local and ou want to use IE well then
2) You will need to edit the security for "trusted sites to allow scripting of downloads and Iframes.
 *      a) open IE
 *      b) Tools -> Internet options
 *      c) Security tab.
 *      d) make sure "trusted site" is highlighted
 *      e) click custom level, Make sure all .Net and .Net reliant components are set to enabled.
 *      f) Enable or prompt all activeX components
 *      g) Enable all downloads
 *      h) Enable .Net framework setup
 *      i) Enable scripting of web browser controls
 *      j) Enable allow websites to open windows without address's or status bars.
 *      k) Enable Launching programs or files from an Iframe.
 *      l) Everything under scripting is set to enabled or prompt.
 * Just so you know, localhost is treated as a "low" security area so tests run on localhost do not need these changes.
 * Refer to   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360